# How can I upgrade the drivers in the Printrboard rev. D?

Tags: stepper-driver

I have a Printrboard rev. D which includes Allegro A4982 drivers. I would like to replace them, but it appears that newer TMC drivers all require several pins for proper operation.

[image]

How can I upgrade the drivers in the Printrboard rev. D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developers from the Klipper firmware confirmed that Klipper doesn't care about the native functions of each pin, therefore it is indeed possible to use the expansion pins for controlling (including UART) TMC stepper drivers.

At this point I cannot confirm, but maybe Marlin allows the same by updating the pin assignments in the source code.

Comment: Marlin does allow so, but you will need to alter the pin declarations. see http://marlinfw.org/docs/hardware/boards.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't. In fact, pretty much all boards with directly soldered drivers are not upgradable.

I'd recommend to buy a proper, contemporary, customizable board like the SKR 1.3 for TMCs.
The Fysetc F6 would also work, but uses "custom" connectors and is still AVR based.

Comment: Since there are still 19 pins available, maybe Klipper firmware can use them. If so I could add three external drivers. If it doesn't work, I can reuse the drivers with the SKR.

Comment: you can't *exchange* the drivers if you can't do Surface Mount Soldering, but you can *circumnavigate* them via pins.